# getting a data from the database and print its like a list on the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i tired to list out data from the databse table and i used the following code

```
public class ViewingGoalsBusinessLayer
{
    public IEnumerable<ViewingGoals> viewinggoals
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                string Connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connectionstring"].ConnectionString;
                List<ViewingGoals> viewgoals = new List<ViewingGoals>();
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ViewGoal", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        ViewingGoals viewgoal = new ViewingGoals();
                        viewgoal.Goal = rdr["Goal"].ToString();
                        viewgoals.Add(viewgoal);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and i got error on the get statement that it not all code paths return a value .
please help me to overcome it

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, not all paths return a value, because no paths return a value.

Declare viewgoals first, and return it last, with the try block around the work in the middle...

Notice in the following MDSN code sample how the get returns a value

```
class Person
{
    private string name;  // the name field 
    public string Name    // the Name property
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx

Comment: i already declare the viewgoals in a seperate class viewgols    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BusinessLayer
{
    class ViewingGoals
    {
        public string Goal { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: And also getting error in the object viewinggoal as ienurable<ViewingGoal> is less accesible